# Vertical lines connecting nodes in Visual Studio editor for XML based code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have seen someone's XAML code that shows like below:

[image]

Basically, a vertical line is shown connecting starting and ending nodes which helps understand the hierarchy of XML based code. I know there might be some extension out there but don't know which one. Please let me know if someone know of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30 this extension does the job for me